# Unbroken chain? Python iteration not being processed

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, iteration

So I've written a bit of code to stack integers in a list from the zeroth position.  For some reason I cannot decipher, the while loop below is not being processed.  I have followed all good style and syntax requirements that I know, and the while loop works when run by itself.

```
def row(line):
    """
    Function that merges a single row or column.
    """
    result_length = len(line)
    print result_length

    # Create a list of zeros the same length as the 'line' argument
    pts_alloc = 0
    dummy = 0
    result = line
    result[0:] = [pts_alloc for dummy in range(len(result))]
    print result

    #Iterate over the 'line' list looking for non-zero entries and 
    #stack them from 'result[0]'
    line_count = 0
    result_place = 0

    while (line_count <= (len(line)-1)):
        if (line[line_count] > 0):
            result[result_place] = line[line_count]
            print result
            result_place += 1
        line_count += 1

    return result
print row([4, 0, 0, 5])
```

Is there a major error in this code that I've missed?  Is there some syntax requirement that I am unaware of?

Comment: `result = line; result[0:] = ` Here, you are modifying `line`! What is this supposed to do? Do you want to move all the non-zero items to the front?

Comment: Did you mean to write `result = line[0:]; result =`?

Answer (score 4):

The problems seems to be this part:

```
result = line
result[0:] = [pts_alloc for dummy in range(len(result))]
```

By replacing a slice of `result`, with `result = line`, you are replacing that same slice in `line`, too, as `result` is just another reference to the same list, not a copy.

Since the slice is the entire list, anyway, just do:

```
result = [pts_alloc for dummy in range(len(result))]
```

Also, you are declaring a lot of unnecessary variables. You could shorten your code to this:

```
def row(line):
    result = [0] * len(line)
    result_place = 0
    for x in line:
        if x > 0:
            result[result_place] = x
            result_place += 1
    return result
```

Or even this:

```
def row(line):
    non_zero = [x for x in line if x > 0]               # take non-zero values
    return non_zero + [0] * (len(line) - len(non_zero)) # pad with zeros
```

Comment: This is a great example of why the "intuitive" approach isn't always the right approach. I get that _moving_ the zeroes around might feel algorithmically safer or more pedantically correct, but there's no reason for it. A zero is a zero non attest what, so it's better to just throw them out and insert "new" ones at the end